# Bootstrap rows on iPad/small screen size are being set a min-height for unknown reason

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

UPDATE: A bit of an anti-climactic finish. There was a random js file that was being included that for some reason was setting the min-height of rows to 30% of the page height. This only happened occasionally though so I'm not exactly sure why it wasn't consistently happening. That was the issue though.

I've been doing some responsive work on a website with bootstrap and have noticed some strange behavior when it comes to rows on ipads/smaller browser sizes.

It seems that for some reason the min-height of these rows are being set on ipads/smaller screen sizes and only on ipads/smaller screen sizes. I've checked through my css to see if anything could be causing this issue and I've search google and haven't had much luck finding an explanation never mind a solution.

```
<!-- BEGIN SLIDE MENU -->
<div id="menu-slide" class="slideout-menu slideout-nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <% if session[:user_name].nil? %>
           <button type="button" id="launch-preference-modal" class="btn btn-default slideout-signin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" style="width:100%;">Sign in</button>
           <button type="button" id="launch-preference-modal" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrationModal" style="width:100%;">Register Now!</button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3 class="collection-heading">Navigation</h3>
        <div class="list-group left-col-nav">
          <%= link_to "/browse", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :remote => true do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span> Recipes
          <% end %>

          <% if session[:user_name] %>
            <%= link_to "/my_recipes", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :remote => true do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> My Recipes
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to "", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :id => "my-recipes-not-logged", :data => { :toggle => "modal", :target => "#myRecipeModal" } do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> My Recipes
            <% end %>

          <% end %>
          <%= link_to "/preferences", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :remote => true do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Channels
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to "/preferences", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :remote => true do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Blog
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to "/preferences", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :remote => true do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Preferences
          <% end %>
          <% if User.authorized_for_faq? session[:access_token] %>
            <%= link_to "/faq_sections", :class => "list-group-item sticky_but", :remote => true do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Manage FAQ
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END SLIDE MENU -->
```

The last row was a test that I put in just to see if the behavior was due to content or something else on the row itself. In the DOM, all three of these rows have "min-height:293px;" on them.

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas? I can get around it by forcing the min-height of these row to be 0 but I don't exactly like that solution so much as I'd like figuring out the root cause.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use the browser's inspect element to find out where the min-height:293px rule comes from?

Comment: I tried that and it seems that it originates from the element and that's all it shows me.

Comment: Do you have some kind of example that you could link to?

Comment: Have you tried media queries?

Comment: Well media queries are how I solve it currently but I want to understand why they are even necessary in the first place. BurningLights I'll try to find an example on our prod server I can link here